# Homomorphism : kernel of a field only has 0

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

i'm new here and i'm struggling to prove that for R,S fields and **f : R → S**

**kernel(f) = {0}**

Definition of kernel is : **kern(f)= { r ∈ R | f(r) = 0 }**

I started the proof but stuck at the start :

∀a ∈ R-{0} => f(a) ≠ 0

Thank you for your help !

Comment: It seems like it's a very larger question, and i'm having difficulties to find what i need from it. thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x \neq 0$, $$1_S = f(1_R)=f(xx^{-1}) = f(x) f(x^{-1})$$

so $f(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: f(x)≠0 because 0 have no multiplicative inverse right ?

Comment: Well if $f(x)=0$ then $f(xa)=0$ for any $a$, but then for any k, $k=xx^-1k$, so $f(k)=0$ for any k.
R being a field means $x^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: @ZackariaBenhouaria Exactly, $0*y=0$ for all $y$, so it cannot be equal to $1$.